# Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String' with Entity Framwork

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, entity-framework

This is my first time I'm trying to use Entity Framework.

I made a database with one table (Paths) and two attributes (PathID, PathName). In vb-net I just want the user to choose a folder with a FolderBrowserDialog and have the path of that folder saved in the column "PathName". When running, I get the error "Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'"

The code is simple and straight forward so I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
Public Class AddPaths
Dim Db_EF As New vs_check_work_Entities
Dim tbl_path As New Paths
Private Sub AddPaths_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub btn_AddPath_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_AddPath.Click
    Try
        Dim FldrBrser As New FolderBrowserDialog

        If FldrBrser.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

            TxtBoxPath.Text = FldrBrser.SelectedPath

            With tbl_path
                .PathName = FldrBrser.SelectedPath
            End With

            Db_EF.Paths.Add(tbl_path)
            Db_EF.SaveChanges()

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        'MsgBox(ex.InnerException)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub PathsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PathsBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Db_EF.SaveChanges()
End Sub
```

End Class

The error happens at

```
Db_EF.Paths.Add(tbl_path)
```

I also tried to test with just adding a string to the table:

```
With tbl_path
                .PathName = "hello world"
            End With

            Db_EF.Paths.Add(tbl_path)
            Db_EF.SaveChanges()
```

I Get the same error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What line does this error occur on. I'm assuming Db_EF.Paths.Add() where you are trying to shove a `path` object into a method that takes a string as input. Also, please paste code/text as text instead of a picture.

Comment: Have been trying all types of things for the past two hours. I'm trying just tbl_path.PathName = "hello world" - Db_EF.Paths.Add(obj_path) -             Db_EF.SaveChanges() but I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My whole EF project wasn't set up correctly. I think I did code first. Now I tried starting with Designer and all works well. Don't know what the problem was but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

May need to see your Entity model.  However, I think that you have a database property called Prompt on your table.  It may be that Prompt is defined as something other than a string but the database expects an nvarchar (or varchar).